# Alarm runs immediately instead of specified time with jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to set an alarm using a TimePicker but the alarm ignores the time sent by parameter and instead it is executed immediately !!

This is my code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    lateinit var navController: NavHostController
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            navController = rememberNavController()
            NotePadReminderTheme {
                SetupNavGraph(navController = navController)
            }
        }
    }
}


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
fun createAlarm(context: Context,time:Long){
    val alarmManager =context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as? AlarmManager
    val intent =Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
    Log.d("receivedtime","time $time")
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, Date().seconds, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    alarmManager?.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent)
    Toast.makeText(context,"Alarma creada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Composable
fun AddPage(navController: NavController, vm: TaskViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val scope= rememberCoroutineScope()
    val title = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val description = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val date = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val time = Calendar.getInstance()

    val iscompleted = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 30.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Agregar Tarea",
            style = NoteTheme.typography.h1
        )

        RowOfThis(title, "Título", true)
        RowOfThis(description, "Descripción", false)
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            DatePick(date)
        }
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            TimePick(time)
        }

        Button(
            onClick = {
                if (title.value.isNullOrBlank() || description.value.isNullOrBlank() ||
                    date.value.isNullOrBlank()
                ) {
                    Log.d("date","date:${date.value}")
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Por favor ingrese todos los datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                    return@Button
                }
                vm.task.value.title = title.value
                vm.task.value.description = description.value
                vm.task.value.date = date.value
                vm.task.value.time = time.timeInMillis
                Log.d("tmepickerreceived","date:${time.timeInMillis}")
                scope.launch {
                    vm.createTask(context, vm.task.value)
                    createAlarm(context, time=time.timeInMillis). //here set the alarm ****************
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Tarea creada correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    vm.resetTask()
                }

            },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Blue)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Guardar", color = Color.White, style = NoteTheme.typography.subtitle)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RowOfThis(value: MutableState<String>, label: String, single: Boolean) {

    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .border(BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Black)),
            singleLine = single,
            maxLines = 3,
            textStyle = NoteTheme.typography.body,
            value = value.value, onValueChange = {
                value.value = it
            }, label = {
                Text(
                    text = label, textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    color = Color.DarkGray,
                    style = NoteTheme.typography.subtitle
                )
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(backgroundColor = Color.White),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onNext =
            { focusManager.moveFocus((FocusDirection.Next)) })
        )
    }
}


@Composable
fun DatePick(mDate:MutableState<String>) {
    val mContext = LocalContext.current

    val mYear: Int
    val mMonth: Int
    val mDay: Int

    val mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    mCalendar.time = Date()

    val mDatePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
        mContext,
        { _: DatePicker, mYear: Int, mMonth: Int, mDayOfMonth: Int ->
            mDate.value = "$mDayOfMonth/${mMonth + 1}/$mYear"
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay
    )
    mDatePickerDialog.datePicker.minDate=Date().time
    Log.d("datepicker","dateset:${mDate.value}")
    Button(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(7.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(0.5f), onClick = {
        mDatePickerDialog.show()
    }, colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color(0XFF227093))) {
        Text(text = "Seleccionar fecha",
            color = Color.White, style = NoteTheme.typography.subtitle)
    }
    Text(text = "${mDate.value}",style = NoteTheme.typography.caption, fontSize = 22.sp, color = Color(0XFF227093))
}



@Composable
fun TimePick(mCalendar:Calendar) {
    val mContext = LocalContext.current


    val mHour = mCalendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY]
    val mMinute = mCalendar[Calendar.MINUTE]

    val mTime = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    val mTimePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(
        mContext,
        {_, mHour : Int, mMinute: Int ->
            mTime.value = "$mHour:$mMinute"
        }, mHour, mMinute, false
    )

    Log.d("tmepicker","time:${mCalendar.timeInMillis}")
    Button(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(7.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(0.5f), onClick = {
        mTimePickerDialog.show()
    }, colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color(0XFF2c2c54))) {
        Text(text = "Seleccionar hora",
            color = Color.White, style = NoteTheme.typography.subtitle)
    }
    Text(text = "${mTime.value}",style = NoteTheme.typography.caption, fontSize = 22.sp, color = Color(0XFF2c2c54))
}
```

The problem I have is that I want the alarm to run at the scheduled time of the DatePicker ad TimePicker but it is running immediately !!

I don't know if this has something to do with the context, but how can I make the alarm be "scheduled" at the time and date of the DatePicker and Timepicker instead of firing at once

Answer (score 0):

Well this was because when you get the calendar month you have to add one for some reason, so that was what caused an inaccurate time when setting the alarm. Final code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val context= LocalContext.current
            AlarmTestTheme {
                mainPage(context)
            }
        }
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Composable
fun mainPage(context: Context) {
    val scope= rememberCoroutineScope()
    val calendar=Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        timeInMillis=System.currentTimeMillis()
    }

    val title = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val description = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val year= remember {
        mutableStateOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR))
    }

    val month= remember {
        mutableStateOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)
    }

    val day= remember {
        mutableStateOf(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
    }

    val hour= remember {
        mutableStateOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))
    }

    val minutes= remember {
        mutableStateOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
    }

    val iscompleted = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 30.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Agregar Tarea"
        )

        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            DatePick(context = context, year = year, month = month, day = day)
        }
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            TimePick(context = context, hours = hour, minutes = minutes)
        }

        Button(
            onClick = {

                Log.d("tmepickerreceived","date and time  :${year.value}/${month.value}/${day.value} : ${hour.value}:${minutes.value}")
                calendar.apply {
                    set(Calendar.YEAR,year.value)
                    set(Calendar.MONTH,(month.value-1))
                    set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day.value)
                    set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour.value)
                    set(Calendar.MINUTE,minutes.value)
                }


                val alarmMgr= context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

                val shuff=(1..99999).shuffled().first()

                val intent= Intent(context,AlarmReceiver::class.java)
                intent.action="alarma"
                intent.putExtra("ALARMA_STRING","alarm number: $shuff")
                val pending=
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,shuff,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

                Log.e("time final","compare ${System.currentTimeMillis()}" +
                        " mytime: ${calendar.timeInMillis} " +
                        "hour: ${calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)} " +
                        "minute: ${calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)} " +
                        "year: ${calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)} " +
                        "month: ${calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1} " +
                        "day: ${calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)}")

                alarmMgr?.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.timeInMillis,pending)

                Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()

            },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Blue)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Guardar", color = Color.White)
        }
    }
}



@Composable
fun DatePick(context: Context, year: MutableState<Int>,month: MutableState<Int>,day: MutableState<Int>) {

    val mDatePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
        context,{d,mYear,mMonth,mDay ->
            year.value=mYear
            month.value=mMonth+1
            day.value=mDay
        }, year.value, month.value, day.value
    )

    mDatePickerDialog.datePicker.minDate=System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000

    Log.d("datepicker","${day.value}/${month.value}/${year.value}")
    Button(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(7.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(0.5f), onClick = {
        mDatePickerDialog.show()
    }, colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color(0XFF227093))) {
        Text(text = "Seleccionar fecha",
            color = Color.White)
    }
    Text(text = "${day.value}/${month.value}/${year.value}", fontSize = 22.sp, color = Color(0XFF227093))
}



@Composable
fun TimePick(context: Context,hours:MutableState<Int>,minutes:MutableState<Int>) {

    val mTimePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(
        context,
        {_, mHour : Int, mMinute: Int ->
            hours.value=mHour
            minutes.value=mMinute
        }, hours.value, minutes.value, false
    )

    Log.d("tmepicker","hour selected :${hours.value}: munute selected: ${minutes.value}")
    Button(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(7.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(0.5f), onClick = {
        mTimePickerDialog.show()
    }, colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color(0XFF2c2c54))) {
        Text(text = "Seleccionar hora",
            color = Color.White)
    }
    Text(text = "${hours.value}:${minutes.value}", fontSize = 22.sp, color = Color(0XFF2c2c54))
}
```